# Snort stream5 preprocessor configuration error

Tags: snort, superuser

Whenever I use bind_to option along with stream5_tcp preprocessor, there
is a error saying "Stream not properly configured.. exiting". The code
stops with at line 617 of spp_stream6.c with if check that says
if(configNotValid). However other stream5 preprocessor options are
working fine. This happens only if I add bind_to. I followed the
ordering as well mentioned in the documentation. This is how my snort
config file looks like

preprocessor stream5_global:
preprocessor stream5_tcp: bind_to 192.168.1.3, policy linux, ports
both 5556 80
preprocessor strean5_udp: ignore_any_rules

*I am using Snort 2.9.9.0.*

Comment: This does not look like a programming question, but network (tool) configuration. Maybe superuser?

Comment: Thanks Mr.Olaf. Snort is written in C, I hoped that somebody might have debugged it

Comment: That's not how this site works! Read [ask]!